# Calling `f()` once regardless of exceptions

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

My understanding may be incorrect but, reading the documentation for `call_once`, it appears that if multiple threads are calling it simultaneously with the same `once_flag` and the first thread throws an exception, one of the other threads will have its callable called (and so forth until one callable returns without throwing).

My question is, if I have multiple thread all the with the same callable and I want the callable to be called truly once regardless of an exception and I want to know about the exception, do I have no choice but to do this:

```
void call_really_just_once()
{
    std::exception_ptr e;

    std::call_once(some_once_flag_, [&]
    {
        try
        {
            may_throw();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            e = std::current_exception();
        }
    });

    if(e)
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a11b0f53fe80725b

Comment: @Mooing Duck, How so? The callable itself will never throw and once it returns `some_once_flag_` will be set to "don't run again".

Comment: oh, now I see it.  Yeah.  All threads block though, until then

Comment: `static bool once = (may_throw(),true);`, though neat, behaves exactly as `call_once`

Comment: @Mooing Duck. You're right about threads blocking. This made me realize that, in the context where I will be using this, I do have the following additional requirement: when you return from `call_really_just_once`, the callable _must_ have been called. i.e. it has to behave just like `call_once` in that regard. I believe my code above fulfills that extra requirement.

Comment: Oh, in that case your code looks ok, just uncommented

Comment: Your question might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/